# Hiding parent folders, give NTFS subfolders full access

Tags: windows-server-2003, permissions, ntfs, file-permissions

On a Windows 2003 server, I need to provide access to a subfolder of the central "project share". The main project folders should not be accessible, preferably hidden, because this access is granted for a freelancer.

Which minimal permissions can be applied to make this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to have a look at the Access Based Enumeration component of Windows 2k3 server ( http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/techinfo/overview/abe.mspx ), which will hide the folders you don't have access to.

Comment: +1, this has to be simultaneously one of the most awesome and also one of the least known features of Windows Server.

Comment: But don't forget that with ABE enabled, there will be an additional load applied to your fileserver, as everytime a user will list a folder, each files and subfolder's permissions will be checked, whereas without ABE these permissions will be checked only when your user tries to access them.